# Effect of ngIf on ngAterViewInit

Tags: angular, visibility, angular-ng-if, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am emitting an event in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook, and listening to that event in another component using ComponentRef. It works well until I use ngIf on the parent component.

So, what is this effect of ngIf on Angular life cycle hooks?

For now, I am setting its visibility to hidden but want to use ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` is removing the component from the dom, and so must the child component would also be removed,
If you only want to hide it use `[hidden]="true"` attribute.

Comment: So ain't the child component will be recreated and ngAfterViewInit will be called again by angular when ngIf is true?

Comment: Yes, it would be. The component get destroyed and when it is true again it will be recreated from scratch, so all the life cycle event would also occur.

Comment: But that's the issue lifecycle hooks are not being called until I scroll or do any other thing on screen

Comment: That was not really mentioned in your question. If thats an issue ur facing the reason should be the change detector is not firing. To fix that check which object its updating its state, you can reset the object urself. Eg inner object reference are missed out but if you create another object with ‘object.assign’ and set it it should do the trick